# android api 23 startActivity error

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, start-activity

have build error for sample below:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public BootReceiver() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context mContext, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
        final Intent l = new Intent();
        l.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        l.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        l.setComponent(new ComponentName(this.getClass().getName(), MainActivity.class.getName()));
        mContext.getApplicationContext().startActivity(l);
    }
}
}
```

broadcast receiver is declared in AndroidManifest.xml inside  tag like this:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

build.gradle is looks like:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
    debug {

    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-leanback-v17:23.2.1'
}
```

but after clean project any make attempt is followed by:

```
Error:(38, 37) error: cannot find symbol method startActivity(Intent)
```

using Android Studio latest stable release.
was tried to restart workstation and Studio (including cache invalidation), reinstall platform, switch to beta Studio version, but have same result.

will be appreciate for any suggestions for this problem. never saw something like this before.

Comment: why you use `mContext.getApplicationContext().startActivity(l);` ? insted of your `mContext.startActivity(l);`

Comment: because i was tried `mContext.startActivity(l);` first with same error as result. so i start believe in magic and try to use some "magic dust" to solve my problem. sadly with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be calm and look all project code. i find a duplicate of `android.content.Context` class in local project's files tree. And there was no `startActivity` method.

duplicate was added to access hidden/system only class fields/methods without java reflection. i'm very very sorry.